# To get records based on a certain value (if value present). If value not present get records based on another value

Tags: sql-server

I have the following table :

```
A  |  B  | C
1    I    as 
2    E    as
1    E    sa
3    I    as 
2    I    sa
3    I    sa 
4    E    as 
4    E    ad
1    I    as
2    D    sd
3    D    sa
```

OUTPUT Table:

```
A  |  B  | C 
1    I    as
2    E    as
1    E    sa 
3    I    as
3    I    sa  
4    E    as 
4    E    ad
```

all those records should be selected which have the value `E` in field B. If the same record (for field A and C) for the record I in field B, then it should not be selected. If there is no value `E` for the values in A and B then the record with field `I` should be selected.

Comment: HUH??? Can you try to explain the rules here a LOT clearer? And how are you planning on getting those values in that order? You have nothing in the data provided to use for ordering your results.

Comment: @SeanLange What do you mean. For every similar record i want the record with the value E in the field B to be selected. If there is no record 'E' in field B then select the same record have record 'I' in field 'B'.

Comment: @SeanLange the order doesnt matter

Comment: This makes no sense at all. What is similar? You have some kind of definition here but you are not sharing it with us. All the rows in that table look similar to me. But I am guessing you have a business rule of what is considered similar.

Comment: @SeanLange by similar i meant records having the same values in all the fields

Comment: Not a single row in your sample data has all the same values in all the fields. Every single row in unique. Seems that Obie was able to read your mind though and found an answer that works for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I see what you're asking:

```
select A, B, C
from myTable t1
where B='E'
or (B='I' and not exists (
  select * 
  from myTable t2
  where t2.A=t1.A
  and t2.C=t1.C
  and t2.B='E'
))
```

Comment: what if there are other values in field  B, but i want only I and E.Sorry i have edited the question

Comment: OK, I changed the answer to only include E and I if there are no E's.